# Comparison between groups

Tags: spss, statistics

What statistical analysis test do I need to run? I want to compare type of downloader (Legal and Illegal) to what type of content they download (Music, Movies etc). In SPSS I have set the type of content as a multiple response set because each respondent could choose multiple content. What is the best test to use to compare this?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for StackOverflow.  http://stats.stackexchange.com/ is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is a kind of vague, my first atempt would be to evaluate the proportion legal and ilegal for each group. See for instance [proportion binomial test](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/idh_ntbi.htm)